# Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

Tags: android

This is the .java file for a small application I am writing in Android through Eclipse, and I am having a minor error or syntax glitch.
at the end bracket marked by asterisks, eclipse is reporting the error 'Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement'. I have searched the code, and find nothing unaccounted for or out of place. Could someone please identify or tell me how to fix this? If you need other files, tell me in the comments. Thanks in advance :)!

```
package org.example.knittingframe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class KnittingFrame extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview); 
        final EditText op1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumBox1);
        final EditText op2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumBox2);
        final Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBox);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int a, b;
        a = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText().toString());
        b = Integer.parseInt(op2.getText().toString());
        int sum = a + b;
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }
    **}** // Here is where the error occurs
    }
 }
```

Comment: Really? .... come on

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right.  You need to replace

```
**}** // Here is where the error occurs
```

with

```
});
```

to finish the `btnAdd.setOnClickListener` method call.

Answer (score 1):

This is a statement in the onCreate(xx) and its an anonymous class, because an anonymous class is a statement you **MUST** terminate the statement:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int a, b;
        a = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText().toString());
        b = Integer.parseInt(op2.getText().toString());
        int sum = a + b;
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }
    **}** // Here is where the error occurs
```

TO:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int a, b;
        a = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText().toString());
        b = Integer.parseInt(op2.getText().toString());
        int sum = a + b;
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an annonymous inner class, you need to end the setOnClickListener method call with ");" as follows:

```
public class KnittingFrame extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview); 
        final EditText op1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumBox1);
        final EditText op2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumBox2);
        final Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBox);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a, b;
                a = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText().toString());
                b = Integer.parseInt(op2.getText().toString());
                int sum = a + b;
                textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
                }
        });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You started a function call: `setOnClickListener()`. You need to finish it. Like so:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int a, b;
        a = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText().toString());
        b = Integer.parseInt(op2.getText().toString());
        int sum = a + b;
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indented properly, maybe you'd see it, but you're missing an extra parenthesis and semicolon:

```
package org.example.knittingframe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class KnittingFrame extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview); 
        final EditText op1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumBox1);
        final EditText op2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumBox2);
        final Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBox);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a, b;
                a = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText().toString());
                b = Integer.parseInt(op2.getText().toString());
                int sum = a + b;
                textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
        });
    }
}
```